# Binary Tree: summation of all nodes between a min and max value

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have an assignment where I am given the root of a randomly generated BST. I am given randomly generated test cases for this assignment.

The assignment description is the following:

> You are given the root node of a binary search tree, T, and two
>   integers: min, and max. Note that min and max are not necessarily stored in the
>   tree. Determine the sum of all keys stored in T that are larger than or
>   equal to min, and smaller than or equal to max. Implement your algorithm
>   recursively

**I am not allowed to have global variables or create helper functions**

my current code is this:

```
private static int problem2(Node root, int min, int max){

 if(root = null){
    return 0;
 }

 if(root.key < min || root.key > max){     
   int lft = problem2(root.left, min, max);
   int rgt = problem2(root.right, min, max);
   int sum = lft + rgt;
   return sum;
 }

}
```

my issue is that if at any point during my recursion, the node trips the base case and causes my function to not complete itself properly.
I believe that my ordering may be to blame.

The node classed is defined as:

```
private static class Node
{
    public Node left = null;
    public Node right = null;

    public int key;

    public Node(int key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it this way: the moment you reach a node which isn't in the desired range, your algorithm stops. What happens if the root itself is out of range? You'll just return 0 right off the bat.
You need to fix your exit condition so that your recursion stops *only* when you've reached a `null`, since you can't know how many nodes that are within range of [min, max] are present in the sub-tree of the node you're currently in. Then, in the recursion itself, you should make the decision whether to add the current node to the overall sum or not.

Possible implementation - **spoilers ahead, I suggest you only look after you've solved it yourself:**

```
private static int problem2(Node root, int min, int max){

 if(root == null){
    return 0;
 }

 int sum = 0;
 // No point in keeping the recursion right/left if the current key is
 // larger/smaller than the desired range - usage of BST property:
 if (root.key <= max) {
    sum += problem2(root.right, min, max);
 }
 if (root.key >= min) {
    sum += problem2(root.left, min, max);
 }
 // If root is within range add it to sum:
 if (root.key <= max && root.key >= min){
    return root.key + sum;
 } else {
    return sum;
 }

}
```

Explanation: each recursive call sums up the results of the left and right subtrees. The key of the node you're currently in is added to the calculation iff it is within the desired range of [min, max].

Comment: This solution of yours is correct, and would work for any kind of binary tree, but this does not really make use of the fact that we have a BST with us here. Using BST properties we can significantly increase this solution's performance, and to me seems like the intent of the question.

Comment: @Ankur You are right. I made an edit to better use the fact that it's a BST ;)

Comment: @YaronGrushka Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Problem I believe lies here:

```
if(root == null || root.key < min || root.key > max){
    return 0;
 }
```

Imagine this case1 : `min:10, max:20, root.key:8`, here this would directly return 0, but it might be possible that there are some nodes on right child of this root that might be within the accepted range.

Similarly, 
case1 : `min:10, max:20, root.key:22`, here this would directly return 0, but it might be possible that there are some nodes on left child of this root that might be within the accepted range.

you need to modify your code in such a way that if `root.key < min`, then look for nodes on right child,
while if `root.key > max`, then look for nodes on left child of the root.

Also, both the `if` conditions in your code are same, hence your flow would never enter the definition of the second `if` block.

Comment: The additional checks was a typo in my code from an earlier attempt. Thanks for pointing that out. Also thanks for clarifying the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Since its obviously an assignment for educational purposes, I won't post a full solution, however I'll give hints that might help:

Basically you do everything right, the method definition is good.

However there are a couple of mistakes in the method itself:

First off, this piece of code:

```
if(root == null || root.key < min || root.key > max){
    return 0;
}
```

The first condition is for the cases where you've reached the end, ok.
But what about the rest? Does the fact that the certain node is less than 'min.' implies that all its "children" also won't be able to "contribute" to the sum and will necessarily be "out of range"?

Disclaimer: I here rely on the fact that its a binary tree (as written in the title of the question), so I don't assume any ordering of elements. Even if its a [Binary Search Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) my comment is still valid (think about why).

Now, the recursion itself:

```
if(root.key < min || root.key > max){     
   int lft = problem2(root.left, min, max);
   int rgt = problem2(root.right, min, max);
   int sum = lft + rgt;
   return sum;
 }
```

What you say here basically is "if my current root's key is out of [min,max] range then enter the recursion". Instead you should be saying "if my current root's key is **within the [min,max] range** then enter the recursion"

Note, that due to my first comment, this code also might change - just keep an eye on the corner cases

Comment: I don't fully agree with this statement : `Instead you should be saying "if my current root's key is within the [min,max] range then enter the recursion"`. It might be possible that the root itself does not lie within the range, but one of its child does. Hence, recursive call should ideally be independent of the state of root w.r.t. the range. Although, given its a BST, we can definitely use the state of the root to decide if we want to invoke traversal for both left and right child or just one of those.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was reviewing the current code only trying to follow the ideas of @CyberknightMk1. I also stated that due to my first comment this piece of code will also likely to be changed (I assume in the direction that you've described). I assumed that the situation that you've described was "supposed to be" handled in the first condition (obviously in a wrong way, hence my first part of the answer)